# Couldn't install bourbon via ember

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli=>2.9.1,node=>9.6.1,bower=>1.8.2,npm=>5.6.0

I have created a sample ember app using following command,

- **ember new**  // to create ember project.
- **ember g template application** //To create template with application.hbs.
- **ember install ember-pikaday** // To install ember plugin
- **ember install ember-cli-sass**
- **ember install ember-cli-bourbon**

The above ember-cli-bourbon command fails with following exception,

```
Cannot find module 'resolve'
Error: Cannot find module 'resolve'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:557:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:484:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vadivel/POC/ember-
    project/sampleProject/node_modules/ember-cli-bourbon/index.js:5:21)
   at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
```

I have also tried following way,

- npm install bourbon //successfully installed
- ember install ember-cli-install // Fails with same error as described above.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If there isn’t a specific reason you are starting with Ember-CLI 2.9, does this work better with Ember 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue in v2.0.0 of ember-cli-bourbon where `resolve` was not included as a dependency. Upgrading to v2.0.1 should solve the issue. To do so, edit your package.json and ensure that the line containing `"ember-cli-bourbon"` specifies `"^2.0.1"` and then run `npm install`.

See https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-cli-bourbon/issues/23 for more information.